# vue.js render data getting 'of undefined'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a problem with rendering data that is in a JSON object. This works fine when I write plain js but does not work when I convert to vue. This was working before I also tried reverting back to an older commit to see if things change but the same issue presists which makes no sense to me.

*I left a lot of code out but this should be the gist of things.*

**TableRecords.vue**

```
<template
   v-for="day in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']">
   <td v-for="shift in ['10-6', '6-2', '2-10']">
      <a href="#"
         v-on:click="record.Status === 'Active' ? showScheduleModal(record.FileNumber, day, shift) : null"
         style="text-decoration: none;"
         v-html="data.schedule[record.FileNumber][day][shift]">
      </a>
   </td>
</template>
```

**data.schedule**

```
{ 
   "954107":{ 
      "Monday":{ 
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: #3831bd\"><b>Non<br>Prod</b></span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: #3831bd\"><b>Non<br>Prod</b></span>"
      },
      "Tuesday":{ 
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Wednesday":{ 
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Thursday":{ 
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Friday":{ 
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Saturday":{ 
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Sunday":{ 
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      }
   },
   "960850":{ 
      "Monday":{ 
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<b>8</b>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Tuesday":{ 
         "2-10":"<b>8</b>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Wednesday":{ 
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<b>8</b>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Thursday":{ 
         "2-10":"<b>8</b>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Friday":{ 
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<b>8</b>"
      },
      "Saturday":{ 
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      },
      "Sunday":{ 
         "6-2":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "10-6":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>",
         "2-10":"<span style=\"color: black\">0</span>"
      }
   }
}
```

**Error**

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Monday' of undefined"
```

Comment: Try console your FileNumber if it exists or not in data.schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was due to some employee's schedules not existing. I just added a check for it.